# Creating a bootable usb or cd with Windows from Ubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, windows, windows-7

I've searched quite a lot but yet didn't found any solution to burn a bootable usb flash or cd/dvd with Windows **from Linux** having an **iso** file with Windows. I've tried `dd if= of= ...` but when I tried to boot from that usb flash, it just didn't boot.

Is there a reliable solution?

Answer (score -1):

You can try Unetbootin for usb's. They generally work!

Or, you can check here to do CD/DVD's:
http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-burn-an-iso-to-a-cd-or-dvd-in-ubuntu

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unetbootin accepts only Linux iso files.

Comment: True.. Forgot about that. :/ Extracting the ISO on a USB also works though for Windows 7 ISO. I have done it!